# Shortest code to throw IllegalArgumentException in Java

Tags: code-golf, java

Okey, we all know the normal way to throw a IllegalArgumentException in Java:

```java
throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // 37 characters
```

But there must be a shorter (as in less characters) ways to do so.
How can we produce a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with even less code?

- The code fragment has to compile and run in java 7.
- No imports/external packages (e.g. not using `java.util.Arrays.toString()` )

  - only exception: java.lang because it is automatically imported.
- You can add own
  methods/classes.
- It must throw a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

  - **Edit:** the error output (stacktrace) must name it java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, so no subclasses of it.

To have a base to start from:

```java
class Titled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

These were all found by `grep`ping the source code in the package `java.lang`.

All of them result in a "pure" `IllegalArgumentException` (i.e. not a subclass of it).

The ones marked `*` only work if you add `" throws Exception"` (18 characters) to your `main` declaration, as they throw a checked exception of some kind.

### 12 (30?) characters*

```
"".wait(-1);
```

This will result in:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
```

### 22 (40?) characters*

```
new Thread().join(-1);
```

### 22 characters

```
Character.toChars(-1);
```

### 30 characters

```
Character.UnicodeBlock.of(-1);
```

Comment: No, it will not compile because it can throw a `InterruptedException`.

Comment: The compiler will error: `unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

Comment: @luckydonald Hm, it does? I tested it on Ideone and it seemed to work.

Comment: Whoops, Ideone automatically adds `throws Exception` to the `main` method. I've added a note in my post.

Comment: Ideone tends to automatically add  `throws java.lang.Exception` which will allow the `InterruptedException` to pass the compiler. (Also Ideone imports `java.util.*` and `java.io.*`)

Comment: Mwhahaha! I managed to find my `IllegalArgumentException` by memory. No need for tools like grep. Except the changed rules make it invalid. :-(

Comment: @Quincunx sorry about that. But it is still an nice way.

Comment: Is `1.wait(-1)` legal in Java? In C# it is.

Comment: @usr No; primitives aren't objects in Java.

Comment: You can get to eleven characters by renaming `args` to `a` and using `a.wait(-1)` instead.

Comment: I thought it was illegal to wait on an object unless you owned the object's monitor, via `synchronized`. (In this case, it could actually matter, too, since the object representing `""` is actually the same object representing every other empty string literal.)

Answer (score 23):

Here's a nice short way to do it, in **<s>17</s> 13 chars**:

```java
new Long("");
```

It throws a `NumberFormatException`, which is an `IllegalArgumentException`. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) and [this](http://ideone.com/5w3M9S) verify it.

Equivalently, one could do

```java
new Byte("");
```

Comment: Sorry, clearified what I am looking for: I am looking a for 'clean' IllegalArgumentException. It should name it so.

Comment: @luckydonald what do you mean by "naming"? The type given in the stacktrace? If so, would an exception-with-cause be acceptable if the IllegalArgumentException was passed internally as the cause to another exception?

Comment: The purpose is to replace the normal throw new IAE(). The code, when executed in a static (main) method has to fail `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at Untitled.main(Titled.java:4)`. Were it fails (line, file, stacktrace) doesn't matter.

Answer (score 10):

## 22 characters:

```java
Character.toChars(-1);
```

[Running example](http://ideone.com/XrWA0t)
Javadoc: [java.lang.Character.toChars(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29)

**Some nice looking variants:**

```java
Character.toChars(~4); // 22 characters, number can be any non-negative (and -0)
```

```java
Character.toChars(1<<7); // 24 characters
```

`~i` is the same as `-1 * (i+1)` because it inverts the bits. So we will get a illegal parameter, because it is smaller then 0.
`1<<7` will create a too high number by shifting the 1 seven times. (same as multiply it 7 times with 2). The last accepted Value seems to be `1114111`, `1114112` will fail. *Note:* this might change depending on your environment, and could be not always reliable.

See the [Oracle Docs "Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and ["Primitive Data Types"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

## 28 characters:

And if you don't like using the character class in a character count competition*:

```java
Enum.valueOf(Enum.class,""); // 28 characters
```

**) Just to make this pun.*

Comment: Doesn't need to be any positive; you can do any non-negative (ie `~0` works too)

Comment: I thought about 0 as a positive because it has no minus. But your right, and even `Character.toChars(~-0);
` works.

Comment: ~0 is -1.  Not sure what ~-0 does for you, besides requiring an additional character.

Comment: It looks funnier xD

Answer (score 8):

## 21 characters:

```
System.getProperty("");
```

As per the documentation, `getProperty` and `setProperty` throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the key is empty.

Answer (score 5):

## 25 Characters

Creates a vector with an invalid (negative) length:

```
new java.util.Vector(-1);
```

Displays:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -1
    at java.util.Vector.<init>(Vector.java:129)
    at java.util.Vector.<init>(Vector.java:144)
    at Titled.main(Titled.java:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's 24 characters:

```
System.out.printf("%z");
```

This will throw an `IllegalFormatException`, which is an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

## 19 characters:

```
String.format("%");
```

Throws `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException`, which inherits from  `IllegalFormatException`, which, in turn, inherits from `IllegalArgumentException`;

Answer (score 1):

## **14 Characters**

```java
this.wait(-1);
```

## **17 Characters**

```java
Thread.sleep(-1);
```

As far as code that directly throws IllegalArgumentException, these will do it.

```
From documentation: 
Thread.sleep(int millis): 
Throws:IllegalArgumentException - if the value of millis is negative
InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread.
```

so direct code is 17 chars, if you're being a super stickler and counting the chars to add a throws clause for the interupted exception you can shorten it by just throwing the raw Exception class

Comment: `this.wait(-1)` does not work in the main function, due to main being `static`.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(-1)` requires you to add a throws declaration to the function, so it gets longer again. `error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`